# Print a list in ordered columns based on the size of the terminal in python

Tags: python, list, operating-system, format

I am writing a version of `ls` in python to learn how to program and in the process get more familiar with some GNU tools, the OS, etc.

I am a little stuck in trying to figure out how to print the output into ordered columns. So if I wanted to print everything into columns I could try a solution along this line:

```
lfile = len(max(ordered,key=len))
padding = 5
total = w // (lfile + padding)
# This code is inside a loop that iterates the list

 lfile = len(max(ordered,key=len))
 print(f'{inode:<1}{blocks:<1} {f:<{lfile}} ', end='')
 if (ordered.index(f) + 1) % total == 0:
     print("")
```

That would yield an output like this:

```
   00    01    02    03    04    05    06    07    08    09    10    11    12 
   13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
```

Which is still not entirely right, but for the sake of argument, I wanted to show the solution I was pursuing.

The problem is that later I realised that `ls` arranges the output into alphabetical columns like this:

```
00  02  04  06  08  10  12  14  16  18  20
01  03  05  07  09  11  13  15  17  19
```

so it makes this more tricky to solve, especially considering that you need to dynamically alter the number of columns depending on number of elements and width of your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, this might help.

```
# columns per line
columns = 8

# space for each number
space = 8

# current column printed
column_index = 0

# our list of numbers
numbers = list(range(1, 31))

# outputs a string with specific length
def blank(string, space):
    return (string + " " * (space - len(string)))[:space]

# output number list
while numbers:
    # pop first element of list
    num = numbers.pop(0)

    # print spaced number
    # next print will be in same line
    print( blank( str(num), space), end="" )

    # increment column index
    column_index += 1

    # if we hit out column limit
    if column_index % columns == 0:
        # print end of line
        print()

# if we didn't hit column limit at last print
# print end of line
if column_index % columns:
    print()
```

You can also you simple list iteration instead of poping:

```
numbers = list(range(1, 31))

for num in numbers:
    # some code
```